# No Unity greeter after installing Xubuntu desktop

Tags: unity, lightdm, login-screen

I installed `xubuntu-desktop` metapackapge on my system and after this action `unity-greeter` no longer appears. I've purged `lightdm` twice, then reinstalled `lightdm` and `unity-greeter`. But still no result. Copying all files from `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` to  `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` returned my Unity greeter but it works incorrectly, for example it asks for my password each time when locking the screen. I've rechecked this option in system settings many times, but it doesn't respond. How to get `lightdm` and Unity greeter back without reinstall of the system?

Answer (score 1):

I had installed `light-locker`, which changed my `lightdm` configuration. Deleting `light-locker` solved my problem.